# How to use a __format__ method from a different class?

Tags: python

I have a class which I want to have the same `__format__` method as another class in some module I have installed in my machine. What would be the correct way to "copy" it into my class, so that it works exactly the same as if I was using the module's class?

Edit: to be specific, I want to use the uncertainties package's `uncertainties.UFloat.__format__` method in a class of my own.

MCVE:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.v, self.u = arg

    def __format__... ?
```

so that, like `UFloat` does:

```
>>> '{:L}'.format(uncertainties.ufloat(1, 0.1))
'1 \\pm 0.1'
```

expected behavior should be the same:

```
>>> '{:L}'.format(MyClass(1, 0.1))
'1 \\pm 0.1'
```

Comment: `MyClass.__format__ = SomeOtherClass.__format__`?

Comment: That sounds like way too tight a coupling between your class and the third-party class. The third-party class's `__format__` may depend on private methods or data attributes that don't exist in your class, or even if it doesn't, it may do so in the future.

Comment: What does `__format__` do? This can make a difference

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga gives `TypeError: unsupported format string parsed to MyClass.__format__`

Comment: @user2357112 Not to be rude, but I want to know anyway. I'll care about those problems later. I'm asking for how to implement a code feature. Although I can appreciate them sometimes, I'm not here asking for advices on best code practices. Thank you.

Comment: @Jaba I'm not sure what you mean. I'll mention my specific problem in the question.

Comment: @mariogarcc Based on your edit. Just import the module in the other file

Comment: Why would you not just build a UFloat and call its `__format__` instead of trying to apply `UFloat.__format__` directly to your object?

Comment: yeah, the as @user2357112 warned, that is likely due to implementation details in `SomeOtherClass.__format__` that we can't see, unless you provide a [mcve], that's the way to "copy the method". And not to be rude, but this question isn't here for you. This is a question and answer site where the questions are meant to be useful to the greater community, so you should expect people to chime in and say "That is not a good practice because of X, Y, and Z"

Comment: @user2357112 Because the idea is to use it as `"{:options}".format(MyClass(args))`

Comment: @mariogarcc the `MyClass.__format__` method would *build the UFloat object in it's own `__format__`* and then *delegate* to it. That is the sane way, because you are using the API the way it is meant to be used. You shouldn't expect that just magically plopping a method into your class from another class is ever going to work except by luck.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you provide an example on how to do that? I've tried returning `uncertainties.UFloat.__format__(self, format_spec)` with no luck.

Comment: There's no way to tell you anything unless you provide a [mcve] and explain what you expect for input/output. `uncertainties.UFloat.__format__(self, format_spec)` is the equivalent of `MyClass.__format__ = OtherClass.__format__` anyway. And this site is definitely for criticizing code, the difference between here and CodeReview is that CodeReview is for *working code*. But if you come here with something that doesn't work, it is a perfectly valid comment to say "Don't do that, it's a bad idea". IOW, if someone asks "How do I shoot myself in the foot" expect people to say "Don't shoot yourself"

Comment: I have added the expected behavior in the question @juanpa.arrivillaga . If it's not clear, tell me why and how I should change it, please.

Comment: try: `return uncertainties.ufloat(self.v, self.u).__format__(format_spec)` or maybe better `return format(uncertainties.ufloat(self.v, self.u), format_spec)`

Comment: Looking at that `MyClass`, copying `UFloat.__format__` into your class was doomed from the start. Your `MyClass` doesn't have the attributes `UFloat.__format__` relies on.

Comment: Note, the above pattern is very common, usually called "delegation" or "forwarding".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga both of those methods work, thank you. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it (because it works, compared to the other answer).

Comment: @mariogarcc I'll write it up when I get off of work in a couple hours, unless someone beats me to it. You are welcome to write it up and accept it yourself! There's nothing wrong with answering your own questinos

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd rather not take the merits of somebody else. Take your time.

Answer (score 1):

One way, as @juanpa.arrivillaga brought up, would be to simply change your method to point to the `OtherClass` method:

```
MyClass.__format__ = OtherClass.__format__
```

This is a pretty clumsy way of doing it, though. I would recommend using a wrapper method to accomplish the same thing, if it's a static method:

```
def __format__(cls, format_str):
    return OtherClass.__format__(format_str)
```

or even convert your current object into the other class and simply call the method, if it's an instance method:

```
def __format__(self, format_str):
    inst = OtherClass(self, format_str):
    return inst.__format(format_str)
```

---

The other solution would be to find the source of `OtherClass`, or carefully observe the behavior, and then essentially rewrite the functionality. Normally I'd do this by looking in the source repository, but a quick pypi search of `uncertainties` and the associated documentation shows no signs of a git repository to draw from, so you'd have to do it the hard way. Python's `inspect` module could help with finding the source code of various components of the library, if that's helpful.

Looking at `uncertainties` in particular, as you present in your question, it looks like the `ufloat` type in the library uses the format function of `AffineScalarFunc`, which is accessible as `uncertainties.UFloat`. You can do this to look at the source code for `uncertainties.UFloat.__format__`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import uncertainties
>>> source = inspect.getsource(uncertainties.UFloat.__format__)
>>> print(source)
```

and you can either try to reverse-engineer/copy the algorithm or figure out how you can adapt your `MyClass.__format__` to pass a value into `uncertainties.UFloat.__format__` that won't crash the other class. I recommend this latter suggestion.

I'm not going to go any further with this solution because that method's code is 459 lines long and I don't feel like messing with that.

Comment: `return OtherClass.__format__(format_str)` wouldn't work, you need to pass the instance somehow.

Comment: Both of these methods don't work because of the reasons some other commenters pointed out, about the attributes/methods my own class doesn't have, but the other class relies on (specifically, it requires my class to have a `_nominal_value` attribute, for example).